# How can I explicitly run a 'make clean' between different targets?

Tags: makefile

I'm looking for the following behavior:

```
# make debug (project is rebuilt. this works fine.)
# make debug (project is not rebuilt because no changes have been made.)
# make release (this is a different target than the currently-built one. I want 'make clean' to run before the release target is built)
# make release (project is not rebuilt because no changes have been made.)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think the best setup is to place all files generated by `make` (object files, libraries, executables etc) into a target-specific directory. This eliminates the possibility of partial builds getting mixed up.

Comment: We do not have separate build directories. This is not possible because processes further downstream from us expect to always find our executables at a given absolute path.

Comment: Do you mean how can you _implicitly_ run `make clean` between targets? To do it explicitly is trivial; just run the command. :)

Comment: I didn't want to run the command _every_ time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. The only way I can come up with to do this, is to externally record the most recent target (e.g. echo it to a file), and then check to see if it is the same or different as the current one. If they are the same, just run the regular build process; if they differ, first run `make clean`.

I made a first attempt at this, to illustrate the process (untested).

```
debug release:
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),$(shell cat last_target.txt))
    $(MAKE) clean
endif
    @echo $@ > last_target.txt
    [regular build commands]
```

This assumes both targets have the same recipe (with different settings for certain variables). If they have distinct recipes, the conditional part and the echo command obviously have to be inserted in both recipes.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I ended up going with a variant of this and it seems to be doing exactly what I was looking for. Furthermore, it gives me per-target control. For example, our build system does a 'make test' as its last build step. My first implementation did a 'make clean' between 'make debug' and 'make test', which broke the ability to actually run the tests which had been built. Having per-target control, I removed this 'make clean' logic from the test target.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have, or should have, separate directories for DEBUG and RELEASE. They should be separate because all intermediaries and executables are different. Then it would be trivial to have separate make targets/context in each directory, with a 'global' one to select the proper make file and continue from there.

Comment: We do not have separate build directories. This is not possible because processes further downstream from us expect to always find our executables at a given absolute path.

Comment: Can't the build process copy the resulting executables to that expected location when the build completes? This will decouple your build from them and also help avoid mixing debug/release.

Comment: We do this on our windows build and I agree it'd be nice on linux, but cannot be done at this time due to external constraints.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, I think the best setup is to have different output directories for different sets of build options. In your case, there'd be an output directory for `debug` and an output directory for `release`. The idea is that all files produced during the build (object files, libraries, executables etc) are placed into the target-specific directory.

This would completely decouple `make release` from `make debug`, and would eleminate the possibility of partial builds getting mixed up.

Comment: This would be the best way, but cannot be done at this time due to external constraints. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the `debug` and `release` targets build the same files, but with different flags.  There's a Mr. Make article called [Rebuilding when CPPFLAGS changes](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/6528--rebuilding-when-cppflags-changes) which describes how to get gmake to do what you need.

Alternatively you could switch to [ElectricMake](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator-dev.php), a gmake-compatible make implementation with many improvements over standard gmake, including a the *ledger* feature which allows the consideration of command-line arguments/compiler flags in the up-to-date check, so you get the behavior you're describing just be enabling that feature:

```
emake --emake-ledger=command debug   ;# builds everything with debug flags
emake --emake-ledger=command debug   ;# does nothing
emake --emake-ledger=command release ;# rebuilds everything with release flags
emake --emake-ledger=command release ;# does nothing
```

(disclaimer: I'm the architect of ElectricMake)